# C# threads that synchronize two cameras

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization

I need to capture images from two cameras and combine them together.

The flow is like this:

- two threads, one for each camera, sample the camera frames.
- Each one sends the frame to a third thread, the consumer.
- Only when the consumer has two frames he processes them,
  and
- releases the capture threads so they can get the next frame.

Can someone outline what I need to do ?
I'm using C# .Net 4.0

Comment: Do you actually need two threads for each camera?  Couldn't you just take the pictures synchronously from your consumer?

Comment: @sachar: There's no need to sign posts on SO. It's done automatically. There's also no need to HTML tags in the post. There's a markdown engine that processes the text. Please see the FAQ for more info.

Comment: I tried synchronously, its too slow.

Answer (score 0):

I would use any static variables or database to store the progress of individual camera's sampling activity. When both camera marks their individual flag as completed, reader flag will consume all frames, reset those flags. Uplon reset of its own individual flag, worker threads start on capturing next frame. You can also use delegate patters (prescriber-subscriber) to inform each other through events.

Answer (score 0):

i'd give each capture-worker 2 AutoResetEvent objects ... one to signal when capturing is done (A), and the other to wait for permission to start the next capture (B) ...

worker routine would be the following loop:

capture to local buffer
signal A
wait for B

consumer loop:

wait for both A
copy both buffers
signal both B
process copys of buffers